# Dialogflow Inline Editor assessing Tensorflow SavedModel running on Docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, axios, dialogflow-es

I have a Tensorflow SavedModel running on Docker. I used the following command within the Docker Quickstart Terminal and it works, giving me predictions and probabilities.

curl -d '{"examples": [{"Features": "abcdefghi"}]}' -X POST http://192.168......:8501/v1/models/exports:classify

I intend to have Dialogflow accessing the Docker Container to get predictions from this SavedModel. How shall I do that?

I noticed one possibility using axios from Youtube by Naresh Ganatra, but do not know how to translate curl json format to axios json format re:"url" & also do not know how to change "response.data.rate".

```
function exchangeRate(agent) {
  var currency1 = agent.parameters["currency-name"];
  var currency2 = agent.parameters["currency-name1"];
  var url = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base='+ currency1  +'&symbols=' + currency2 ;
  return getRate(url).then(response => {
  var bot_response = "The exchange rate is " + response.data.rates[currency2];

  console.log(bot_response);
  agent.add(bot_response);
  }).catch (error => {
    console.log("Something is wrong  !! ");
    console.log(error);
    agent.add(bot_response);
});
};

function getRate(url) {
    const axios = require('axios');
    return axios.get(url);
}
```

Can anyone help? I am new to programming, please bear with me. Thanks!

I have created a Ngrok tunnel to reach the model, but I get a "Malformed request" or "Bad request" with various attempts I have made to change the above codes in relation to URL, data and response.

Appreciate your assistance !

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to find the answer myself. Successfully connected to Docker Tensorflow through Ngrok and get predictions to be displayed at Dialogflow.

```
function predict(agent) {
  let data = agent.context.get('havehistory').parameters.any;  
  var dataString = '{"examples": [{"Features": "' + data + '"}]}';
  var options = 'http://1234567.ngrok.io/v1/models/exports:classify'; 

  return getRate(options,dataString).then(response => {
  var bot_response = "The answer is " + JSON.stringify(response.data.results);
  agent.add(bot_response);
  console.log(bot_response);
  }).catch (error => {
    console.log("Something is wrong  !! ");
    console.log(error);
    var bot_response = "Something is wrong: " + response.data;
    agent.add(bot_response);
});
}

function getRate(options,dataString) {
    const axios = require('axios');
    return axios.post(options,dataString);
}
```